# Remove any row in a dataframe where the length of a zipcode is not equal to 5 digits

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with zipcodes:

```
address <- as.data.frame(matrix(c('1111 Spam Street', '12 Foo Bar', '666 Dead End', 95524, 94118, 9021), ncol=2))
address$V2 <- as.numeric(as.character(address$V2))
```

Which looks like this:

```
    V1                   V2
1   1111 Spam Street    95524
2   12 Foo Bar          94118
3   666 Dead End         9021
```

Unfortunately, the last zipcode is incorrect and I would like to remove that row and end up with just this:

```
    V1                   V2
1   1111 Spam Street    95524
2   12 Foo Bar          94118
```

My attempt  `newaddress <- address[length(address$V2) != 5, ]` is obviously wrong, because it is looking at the length of the column, not the values inside the column.

How can I remove any row in a dataframe where there is a numeric value in a column which is not 5 digits in length?

Any advice is appreciated, and I apologize in advance for such a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
newaddress <- address[nchar(address$V2) ==5 , ] #would also remove rows with more than 5 digits
```

EDIT after comment by @Matt:

Assuming the values in `address$V2` are integer, you can also do the following:

```
address[address$V2 >= 10000 & address$V2 <100000, ]
```

Comment: aha!  `nchar` is what I was missing!

Comment: @MattO'Brien it works without any problems or warnings on my machine. But I also included another approach for numeric values. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr) 

address %.% filter(nchar(V2) == 5)
```